# Access SQL > Select "Height" out of some text

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, split

I've got an Access Database filled with some product-informations.
unfortunately data like height, width etc. isn't in a separated column.
So I was wondering how I could use some SQL so I can filter/split those values.

For example it looks like this:

```
Table: SHP_PRODUCT

Field: SHORT_DSC

Value: Candle "Country", Height 120mm, Diameter 50mm, red

Result should be: "120mm"
```

Note: The height doesn't always have the same position like "It's the second word". Also I can't guarantee it's comma-separated.

Comment: Does height always come in the same format like **Height xxxxxmm**?

Comment: It can be mm, cm or m. But it's always like "BlankNumberUnit"

Comment: Is BlankNumberUnit always preceeded by the word **Height**?

Comment: Yes it is. Otherwise I will change it so there will be the word "height".

Comment: Your data is non-relational (1NF violation) so don't use SQL. Either fix the data, so the SQL becomes obvious (`SELECT height_in_metres FROM SomeTable`) or use a more appropriate language (Python?). Would recommend using the other language to do a one-off data transformation so you can use SQL going forward.

Comment: @onedaywhen puuh, I'm no pro when it comes to stuff like that :S All I know about sql is kinda what Google tells me when I have a problem. So I would need an extended manual to do what you suggested

Comment: I'll try to be more plain: if a query as simple as `SELECT height_in_metres FROM YourTable` can't be done then there's something wrong with your data, it is not in the 'structure' SQL expects. SQL is simply the wrong tool for the job (arguably, a database is the wrong tool for the job e.g. looks like your data is more like a document so therefore a document management system might be better).

Comment: Yea, but I can't do anything about the data. It's what "they" served me, so I have to deal it it somehow. But the solution by Steeefan seems to head to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using RegEx?

```
Public Function extractHeight(ByVal val as String) As String
    Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim regExMatches As Object

    regEx.Pattern = "Height\s[\d*\,*\.*]+[a-z]{0,1}m"
    regEx.Global = False
    Set regExMatches = regEx.Execute(val)

    If regExMatches.Count > 0 Then
        extractHeight = Replace(regExMatches(0), "Height ", "")
    Else
        extractHeight = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Use in query as aforementioned

The regex pattern `Height\s[\d*\,*\.*]+[a-z]{0,1}m` matches for a string that begins with "Height", followed by a space, then a number of whatever length with '.' or ',', then a string such as cm, mm, m.

Make sure to add `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` to References in the VBA edtior (`Extras - References`)

Comment: Looks really nice this far. Only problem: The result still shows the word "height". It should be just the value/number (+cm, m, whatsoever)

Comment: I edited my code to reflect this (`Replace(regExMatches(0), "Height ", "")`)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed - and of course thanks to all the others, as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can create small function to retrieve this:

```
Public Function ExtractHeight(ByVal Value As String) As String

    Dim Parts As Variant

    Parts = Split(Value, "Height")
    If UBound(Parts) > LBound(Parts) Then
        ExtractHeight = Replace(Trim(Split(Parts)(1), " ")(0)), "m,", "m")
    End If

End Function
```

Then use that in your query:

```
Height: ExtractHeight([SHORT_DSC])
```

Comment: This would work as long as it's comma-separated, which isn't always the case (mentioned above). Maybe split at the first space and remove any excess comma's at the end (given you trim out the space after "Height")?

Comment: First of all: It works in general! But I noticed two problems. 1. some heights are like "2,5cm", so the result is just "2", because there is already a comma. Perhaps we can say "from blank to blank"? 2. not every product has a height and it seems like it causes some troubles. But I'm not so sure about it. If the product has no height it displays #error and Access wants me to debug it a couple of times.

Comment: That's where all the trouble comes in and you have to be creative. See edit.